# Does there exist a smooth approximation of $x \bmod y$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm looking for a function $m(x,y)$ that smoothly approximates $x \bmod y$, and I'm assuming there would be some $n$ or $\varepsilon$ in the body of $m(x,y)$ that defines the degree of approximation such that as $n$ goes to infinity or $\varepsilon$ goes to zero, 
$$
m(x,y)= x \bmod y.
$$

I've looked at, for example, $\sin(x/y)$ and have been trying to figure out ways to make $\sin(x)$ more "steep" so that I can apply such techniques to $\sin(x/y)$ in order to perhaps more closely approximate $x \bmod y$.

The analogy I'm looking at is the approximation of $\mid x\mid$ as $\sqrt{x^2 + \varepsilon)}$ where epsilon is some small quantity.

Does a similarly smooth function exist for $x \bmod y$?

Comment: The edit looks nice but technically ruins your question. The function $m(x,y)=x$ satisfies the equation $m(x,y)\equiv x \pmod y$ for all integers $x$ and $y,$ but that "solution" is clearly not what you wanted.

Comment: The way to format the operator you wanted is to write `x \bmod y` in MathJax; this typesets to "$x \bmod y$". It's a known, legitimate binary operator on two integers.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I'm not so familiar with x (mod y) notation to be honest, so should I just revert to writing it out as I don't know latex either?

Comment: I think it is what you want now. No need to revert back to plain text.

Comment: Nvm, thanks for the tip, the question's updated.

Comment: Now I just need to go think about the actual question a bit ... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\theta=\pi x/y$. @user2249675's answer involves a term $\cot\theta=\cos\theta/\sin\theta$. We can construct a smooth approximation by replacing $1/\sin\theta$ with $\sin\theta/(\sin^2\theta+\epsilon^2)$, giving the final answer
$$m(x,y)=y\left(\frac12-\frac1\pi\arctan\left(\frac{\cos(\pi x/y)\sin(\pi x/y)}{\sin^2(\pi x/y)+\epsilon^2}\right)\right).$$

Here is a plot with $y=5$:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the fourier series for the sawtooth wave might be helpful here.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html

The series is given by

$$x=\frac{L}{2}-\frac{L}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{2n\pi x}{L},\quad x\in(0,L).$$

If $x\notin(0,L)$, the Fourier series gives $x\mbox{ mod } L$, which is what is wanted here. Truncating at finite order gives a continuous approximation of $x\mbox{ mod }L$.

Comment: Though the Gibbs phenomenon would mean the partial sums won't converge uniformly to the sawtooth function, which may or may not make it unsuitable for the OP's purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple answer you can try:
$$m(x,y) = y\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\arctan(\cot(\pi x/y))}{\pi}\right)$$
Plot with $y = 5$:

[image]

Comment: The question asked for "smooth". I don't know if it really meant smooth in the mathematical sense, but this function isn't even continuous.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I found was to find a smooth floor function, and then simply apply it to the equation:

$$
x \bmod y=x-{\lfloor}\frac{x}{y}{\rfloor}y
$$

And a definition for the smooth floor function I derived is:

$$
{\lfloor}x{\rfloor}=-\frac{1}{2} + x + a ln(1/a) -\frac{i}{2 \pi} \left[ln\left(1-e^\left(-2 i \pi \left(x+a 
 ln(1/a)\right)\right)+a\right) - ln\left(1-e^\left(2 i \pi \left(x+a 
 ln(1/a)\right)\right)+a\right) \right]
$$

As you make *a* smaller and smaller, this increasingly approximates the floor function.

**Update**

I realized after posting that @user856 had already posted a much simpler approximation quite a while ago.

Comment: Where is $y$ in your formula ?

Comment: I tried this formula. It does not get the desired result. Is there a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I missed @dtn's comment; yes there was a typo: that y shouldn't have been there in the smooth floor function approximation.