# Continous, Non-Fourier, Trigonometric Approximation of the Fractional Part Function

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, fractional-part

I would like to know a single (not piecewise) continuous approximation of $x \bmod 1$ which gets sharper the more you increase a constant $c$. I do not want a series like Fourier, but I do want something that uses continuous trigonometric functions (though $\arcsin$ is fine).

Comment: $\arctan(\sin x/\cos x)$ has the shape you want. Now replace the $1/\cos x$ factor with a continuous approximation, say $\cos x/(c + \cos^2 x)$ as $c\to0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491494/does-there-exist-a-smooth-approximation-of-x-bmod-y

Comment: I've added an answer there now, FYI.

Comment: @Rahul I think you meant $\arctan(\cos x/ \sin x)$

Comment: @Rahul Thank you! Can you put your comment as an answer?

Comment: I did. Didn't you see my last comment?

Comment: @Rahul I meant on this question.

Comment: Then no, I have already added an answer there that you can refer to.