# Are there other 2-argument trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry

Are there any other trigonometric functions with 2 arguments, like [$\mathrm{atan2}(x,y)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), but free from its drawbacks, like the need to adjust the range from $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ to $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: I don't consider $\operatorname{atan2}$ a "trigonometric function"; it's simply a utility that returns the polar angle associated with Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$. Despite the name, it is not some variant of $\arctan$ that has had its range "adjusted". (I believe it would be more appropriate to call the function, say, $\operatorname{arg2}$, given its association with the [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) of a complex number.)

Comment: yes this is the arctangent2, only the problem persists (I'm talking about the range)

Comment: @omjoglekar can you tell me then how the map range is 0-2 pi?

Comment: oh......havent studied that. all i know is tan^-1 (x) or the inverse tangent aka arctan (x)

Comment: @dtn: I guess I'm not clear on your question. By my reading, you were simply stating an opinion that a "drawback" of $\operatorname{atan2}$ (compared to $\operatorname{arctan}$?) is "the need to adjust the range" from $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ to $[0,2\pi)$ ... although the range of $\operatorname{atan2}$ is actually $(-\pi,\pi]$. (I was letting that slide.) ... Are you instead asking for a variant of $\operatorname{atan2}$ that returns angles in the range $[0,2\pi)$? (If so, then you can always just add $2\pi$ when $\operatorname{atan2}<0$.)

Comment: @omjoglekar "Are you instead asking for a variant of atan2 that returns angles in the range [0,2π)? (If so, then you can always just add 2π when atan2<0.)" yes this is what i'm looking for (alternatively)

Comment: Side remark: $\operatorname{atan}2$ is a newcomer (invented around 40 years ago for computer needs, in particular for graphical needs). I am happy to use it but it is devoided of any theoretical interest.

Comment: @JeanMarie depending on where and how to use, take if control systems - there are colossal scope for applied questions of mathematics, incl. trigonometry

Comment: I haven't said that trigonometry is devoided of interest. I even think it a very important tool !

Comment: @JeanMarie I understood you. Atan2 originated as an auxiliary tool, but in fact there are important uses for it.

Comment: @omjoglekar please see my answer;

Comment: @Blue please see my answer;

Comment: @JeanMarie please see my answer;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following solution. Use the material from here.

https://wumbo.net/formula/angle-between-two-vectors-2d/

This formula calculates the angle between two vectors in a range $[-\pi;\pi]$.

To scale to a range $[0;2\pi]$, use the *modulo* `Mod`:

$new_{\theta}=Mod[\theta+360,360]$ or $new_{\theta}=Mod[\theta+2\pi,2\pi]$, if using radians.

For a smooth approximation of the `Mod`, use the [Does there exist a smooth approximation of $x \bmod y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491494/does-there-exist-a-smooth-approximation-of-x-bmod-y). Get a smooth `atan2` that covers angles in a range $[0;2\pi]$. Simplest solution I know.

Dear experts, please check my solution.

Comment: $\operatorname{Mod}[\theta+2\pi,2\pi]$, when applied to $\theta$ between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ (well, more than that, but that's all you need here), amounts to the same thing as my commented suggestion: *Add $2\pi$ if $\operatorname{atan2}$ is negative.* I don't really see a need to *smoothe* this operation, but I've been unclear about your intentions before. :)

Comment: @Blue Yes! But, your proposed solution requires the introduction of conditions that toggles the function. I don't really like that :)) As for "differentiability". In my problem, the 2-argument arctangent had to be smoothed by eliminating the discontinuities (which is achieved by changing the $\epsilon$ parameter), but I do not know how the derivative of the $Mod$ function is sought. Therefore, I tried to find its smooth and differentiable counterpart.

Comment: Well, as long as you're happy. Cheers!

Comment: @Blue Thank you very much :)